# Why jquery pjax is not defined when using jquery ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

Why jquery pjax is not defined in the js file, but it's defined in the console if i type `$.pjax`

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
  callback = (typeof callback != 'undefined') ? callback : {};
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: callback,
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
  });
}

$('document').ready(function() {
  $.when(
    loadScript('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.10.0/codemirror.min.js'),
    loadScript('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.pjax/1.9.6/jquery.pjax.min.js')
  ).done(function() {
    $('.loading').hide().next().css({
      'visibility': 'visible',
      'overflow-y': 'auto',
    });
    console.log($.pjax() + ' ...');
  });

});
```

it console this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $.pjax is not a function`

Comment: FYI...there is shortcut `$.getScript()` you could also use

Comment: with `$.getScript()` you can't cache the sctipt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loadScript function does not return a promise, so from the point of view of $.when, your scripts load immediately, which is not the reality.

Try change the line :

```
$.ajax({
// ...
})
```

to

```
return $.ajax({
// ...
});
```

so you return a promise for $.when

Comment: @elkebirmed It appears that the promise resolves when the script is downloaded, and not when it executes, even for dataType: "script"

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here.

- You have to return a promise that is returned by $.ajax
- $.when accept one argument which is array

ie

```
function loadScript(...) {
 ... 
 return $.ajax
}

$.when([loadScript('a'), loadScript('b')]).then(...)
```

Comment: not true about $.when...in fact it does not accept array and have to use `apply()` if it is array

Comment: $.when accept one argument which is array:

The docs seem to indicate otherwise, see this line: `$.when( d1, d2 )` on this page https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: `{"readyState":1}` is returned by using `console.log(JSON.stringify(_$));` which is a variable holding `_$ = $.ajax......`

Comment: JSON.stringify does not include methods, which are the important part of promises. It'll have a number of methods such as .then etc.